# How to revert back in git?

Tags: git, revert

I revert my code to previous version, now I want to revert it back to my latest version. 
How can I do that ? Thanks

Comment: *How* did you revert? By rewriting history (`git-reset`) or by using `git-revert`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
git checkout master
```

(or what did You mean by revert?)

Answer (score 1):

You can walk back through the history of individual refs (tags, branches, checkouts)  with e.g. `HEAD@{1}`, the last place you checked out before this one, and you can get a nice historical table of contents with `git log -g --decorate --oneline`.

William Pursell pointed out `git reflog`, a much simpler command than git log, focused only on  the work-history logs in `.git/logs`.

Comment: @WilliamPursell can't forget what I didn't know ... this is why I reread docs, and came to answer questions here ... thanks!  updating.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by 'revert' ? *git revert* ?

You can use `git reset --soft YOUR_SHA` to point HEAD to a specific commit. Or a simple `git checkout master` to return back to the 'trunk' if you are lost in a "detached head" status...

The answer depends really on what your current status is.

Answer (score 0):

if you used

`git checkout <commit hash>`

then your code is in a detached state, meaning it belongs to no branch. you can simply do a  `git checkout branch_name`  to bring code to the latest revision

---

if you used

`git reset <commit hash>`

then you can clean up your changes and then

`git pull`

or if you remember the  `<commit hash>`  of your latest revision,

`git reset <commit hash>`